# Building a Router.go() command in an event handler

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I can't seem to get the syntax for this right.

I have an event on a class, and upon the click on the class, I want to have a the user sent to a different route based on parameters in context. What's below is wrong, but hopefully shows what I'm trying to accomplish.

```
'click .foo': function(){
     param1= this.param1; param2 = this.param2;
     Router.go("routName", param1, param2)
}
```

Comment: Just to avoid confusion in the future: it's not a helper, it's an event handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a quick example to get you started :

```
<template name="parent">
  {{> child childContext}}
</template>

<template name="child">
  <a href={{pathFor "my-route"}}>
    Go to my route with parameter = 'value'. (/my-route/value)
  </a>
</template>

Template.parent.helpers({
  childContext:function(){
    return {
      parameter:"value"
    };
  }
});

this.route("my-route",{
  path:"/my-route/:parameter"
});
```

I think you want to use an anchor with `href` value computed thanks to the `{{pathFor}}` helper.

`{{pathFor}}`, `Router.path` and `Router.go` all take the same arguments :

- the route name as first argument.
- an object which is used as data context to compute the resulting path.

For example in `my-route`, we have a path which is `/my-route/:parameter`, so when we want to compute a dynamic path using some data context, we must ensure this data context is an object having a parameter property.

Using a `button` + `Router.go` is probably not appropriate for redirecting a user to some other URL in your application (this is what anchors do right ?), but this is how we could do it :

```
<template name="child">
  <button type="button">
    Go to my route with parameter = 'value'. (/my-route/value)
  </button>
</template>

Template.child.events({
  "click button":function(event,template){
    Router.go("my-route",this);
  }
});
```

Comment: "Using a button + Router.go is probably not appropriate for redirecting a user to some other URL in your application (this is what anchors do right ?)" - what do you propose for handling a submit event (using the iron-router) then ?